# How to allow Multi-Window feature Activity wise in Android N?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest, android-7.0-nougat

How to enable Mutli window option in android app Activity wise.?

I tried with AndroidManifest activity attribute `android:resizeableActivity` in two separate activities.

***From Android-N Documentation what I found for above option***

```
android:resizeableActivity=["true" | "false"]
```

> If this attribute is set to true, the activity can be launched in
>   split-screen and freeform modes. If the attribute is set to false, the
>   **activity does not support multi-window mode.** If this value is false,
>   and the user attempts to launch the activity in multi-window mode, the
>   activity takes over the full screen. If your app targets Android N,
>   but you do not specify a value for this attribute, the attribute's
>   value defaults to true.

**What I tried** :

Added Two Activities One Activity is with `android:resizeableActivity="false"` and second Activity is with `android:resizeableActivity="true"` (in `AndroidManifest.xml`).

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MWActivity"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

For both Activities app is  able to enable Mutli-window & able to Resize also.

**Expected behavior as per documentation** :

only `MainActivity` should allow to Mutli-Window & `MWActivity` should not be allow to resize also as i have given `android:resizeableActivity="false"` to `MWActivity`

> ***UPDATE :  As of now (In Current Version of "N") it can be consider as a Defect***

This is defect in the current version of "N". From code.google [check this link for more detail](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205216) .

Will keep updating answer & question if anything I got.

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: `minSdkVersion 'N'`  `targetSdkVersion 'N'`

Comment: OK, so it's not a matter of Android N ignoring your attributes due to a lower `targetSdkVersion`. You might consider creating a full project that can reproduce the problem, then [filing an issue about it](https://developer.android.com/preview/bug).

Answer (score 3):

This is as expected and as mentioned in Android documentation. That is a root activity's attribute settings apply to all activities within its task stack. For example, if the root activity has android:resizeableActivity set to true, then all activities in the task stack are resizeable.

In your case you have android:resizeableActivity set to true for root activity so all activity created in same task will support multi-window.

Same is documented in https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html#configuring

Comment: I don't get what the "resizeableActivity" do. Even if it's not being set, I can still have a split screen of the app together with another app on the other side. Can you please explain what it does, and how to test it?

Comment: The Android documentation says that the default value for resizeableActivity is true on API level 24 and up:

"If your app targets API level 24, but you do not specify a value for this attribute, the attribute's value defaults to true."

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do it programmatically by starting you activity as a new task only if you are in multi-window mode.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MWActivity.class);
if (isInMultiWindowMode())
{
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
}
startActivity(intent);
```